# Access multiple pc's with text file full of IP's

Tags: bash

I already written a script to delete files on pc's.  I have a text file full of IPs, how do I edit the script to access all the pc's? all the computers has the same username and password and can I just add the commands above my script?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you have working so far?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this might do what you want?

```
for machine in $(cat machines.txt);
do
   scp myscript $mymachine
   ssh $machine myscript
done
```

It is likely you will need to administer these machines in future, so I suggest you look into configuration management tools like chef or puppet